# recursively_embeds_many not persisting

Tags: mongoid

I have a really simple model

```
class Region
  include Mongoid::Document
  recursively_embeds_many

  field :name, type: String
end
```

I can assign a parent and it seems to work, but the data doesn't persist after saving.

```
> region1.parent_region = region2
> region2.child_regions
[region1]

> region1.save    
> Region.find(region1._id).parent_region
nil
```

What am I doing wrong?